# Istio missing metrics

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, grafana, istio, jaeger

I am testing Istio 1.1, but the collection of metrics is not working correctly.

I can not find what the problem is. I followed [this tutorial](https://istio.io/help/ops/telemetry/missing-metrics/) and I was able to verify all the steps without problems.

If I access prometheus I can see the log of some requests.
[image]

On the other hand, if I access Jaeger, I can not see any service (only 1 from Istio)
[image]

Grafana is also having some strange behavior, most of the graphs do not show data.

Comment: kind of hard to say what you have missed... any errors/warn/hints in any logs...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In istio 1.1, the default sampling rate is 1%, so you need to send at least 100 requests before the first trace is visible.

This can be configured through the `pilot.traceSampling` option.

Comment: Yes, I think it was part of the problem. Using the port name convention I think it also helped solve the problem https://github.com/istio/istio.io/blob/master/content/help/faq/traffic-management/naming-port-convention.md